# WPF - Wait for task to finish before running next

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, task, .net-4.5

I want to wait for an operation to finish before directly continuing with the next operation.

(Operation 1)The program deserializes a viewmodel and displays the data in a datagrid.

(Operation2) The program sets the required height of the window.

(Operation3) The program renders and saves an image of the datagrid.

(Operation4) The program closes.

Right now the program crashes because I believe certain operations dont have the required time to complete properly. When I had a messagebox show at the top of the code it worked fine. Working in VS 2015 .net 4.5, how can I achieve this?

```
        //MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        BinaryFormatter reader = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var file = File.Open(v, FileMode.Open))
        {
            this.Vm = (ViewModel)reader.Deserialize(file);
        }
        this.DataContext = Vm;


        myRef = (CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["ColViewSource"];

        properHeight = (myRef.View.Groups.Count - 1) * 50;

        foreach (var item in Vm.Collection)
        {

            properHeight += 55;
        }
        this.Height = properHeight;
        CreateBitmapFromVisual(grid, "picture.png");
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: "Right now the program crashes", could you provide an exception being thrown?

Comment: Use (Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);)-like codes in order to make sure everything is ready.

Comment: Thanks Ramin, works!

Comment: @AudoAnzon I add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your app getting crashed because of posted sample code. There must be some other code in your project which is causing crash when you try to shutdown your app using following line.

```
  Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Not to mention but you can validate your code using F10 in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in order to make sure everything is ready:

```
 Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

[This table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx) might help you decide which *DispatcherPriority* is more appropriate.